# How to run a service in sleep mode in Android

Tags: android

I wrote an android service, which search for GPS every 5 minutes. I have used a timer inside the service. But this timer is not running when the phone is in the sleep mode.

Can't I run a service when the phone is in sleep mode?
How can I over come this problem? pls help me.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a `Service` I would recommend that you take a look at the `AlarmManager` class. Depending on what you are trying to achieve this could be the better way to go. Using `AlarmManager` you can schedule a task (piece of code) to be executed at a given point in time. When you set an alarm you can set it's mode to `RTC_WAKEUP` which will wake the device up if it's sleeping and run the code associated with the alarm.

Take a look here for more details:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html